# C# talking to C++ library - AAF SDK

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke

I'm trying to read AAF files (that describe edited video and audio sequences) in c#. AAF is open source, and there's a C++ SDK available http://sourceforge.net/projects/aaf/.

I'm a C# coder and while I understand some of the C++ coding paradigms, my C++ is basically non-existent.

I presume the intereaction is possible using pinvoke which I've used before for interacting with Win32. With win32 I've pulled calling information from pinvoke.net, but I'm not entirely sure how I go about defining the pinvoke entry points from scratch with a third party SDK.

Can anyone help me to get started on this? For instance, what are the first steps in pinvoking a third party C++ library? Are there tools for helping automate this process?

Comment: Your question is too broad and borderline off-topic (tool request). That said, I am not sure you can use pinvoke, but the standard way to work with native C++ libs in .Net is through Managed C++. You can probably get away with just the basics.

Comment: C++/CLI mixed mode is what you need

Comment: @Stephen Ellis do you had success? Maybe you could help me?

Comment: Sorry. I never persued it.

Answer (score 1):

You have basically two ways of doing that:

### Using C++ Interop (implicit PInvoke)

[Visual C++ can interop with native C++ code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2x8kf7zx.aspx). So you can use Visual C++ as a bridge between the native C++ and C#. Basically you have to write wrapper (or "proxy") classes in visual C++ to interact with your native C++ objects. 
Under the hood, this method uses PInvoke (therefore "implicit PInvoke") with specific options, but it has the advantage of retaining the object-oriented structure of the native C++.
Note that this method is not portable to Mono.

### Using good ol' PInvoke

[You can use PInvoke with C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eyzhw3s8.aspx) the exact same way as you use PInvoke with C.
There is however a limitation: you cannot PInvoke C++ methods this way, so you lose the C++ object-oriented structure.
If the library that you are using provides a C API, you can use that. Otherwise, you have to create a small C++ wrapper that will wrap the C++ API in the form of C-style free functions.
If you have a lot of classes to wrap this way, you can use SWIG to wrap automatically. As a bonus, [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) recreates the object-oriented structure in C# via some guru code generation. However using SWIG requires some setup and I don't think it is necessary if you only need a few functions.