# Limitations of C++ Interop (implicit PInvoke)

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke

I would like to use some native (unmanaged) C++ in C#. What I found out is that I have two options, explicit and C++ Interop (implicit pinvoke).

[Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/using-cpp-interop-implicit-pinvoke?view=vs-2019) recommends implicit over explicit. But there is not much information about what I can and cannot do this way. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24525394/c-sharp-talking-to-c-library-aaf-sdk/24525969#24525969) said in 2014 that implicit does not work with Mono, and would therefore not work on Linux systems. But what is the situation today?

I want to use the C++ library on any platform (win,mac,linux,android,ios) from my C# applications. It's a header-only template library written in C++14. I would like to know if I can use the recommended C++ Interop to do this or whether I have to write a C-Style API and use explicit PInvoke for this.

Best regards

Thorsten

Comment: Be sure to include the `unity3d` tag when asking questions about Unity. Unity has some different "best practices" than normal coding and good advice for normal programs may be bad advice for Unity, adding the tag makes it so people who know the difference are more likely to see your question.

Comment: Thanks, but my question wasn't about Unity. I need this for "plain" C# applications

Comment: I'd take a look on these two repos, where author has wrapped same library (Bullet physics engine) using PInvoke and managed C++. https://github.com/AndresTraks/BulletSharpPInvoke https://github.com/AndresTraks/BulletSharp Also, you will need some source files (probably C API) to compile these templates out of header-only library.

Comment: Also, `BulletSharpUnity` (https://github.com/Phong13/BulletSharpUnity3d) uses `BulletSharpPInvoke` internally, in order to be usable on multiple platforms, including Android.

Comment: It is not what you think it is, in both cases you need a C++/CLI compiler.  Which does provide the option to do it both ways (directly calling a C function vs using [DllImport]).  You'll never get cross-platform support from C++/CLI, you do need to provide a C interface so you can use [DllImport].

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [Unity's documentation for Native dll files](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/NativePlugins.html) they show you should use explicit interop when doing P/invoke with Unity. Here is their example from the docs:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class SomeScript : MonoBehaviour {

   #if UNITY_IPHONE

   // On iOS plugins are statically linked into
   // the executable, so we have to use __Internal as the
   // library name.
   [DllImport ("__Internal")]

   #else

   // Other platforms load plugins dynamically, so pass the name
   // of the plugin's dynamic library.
   [DllImport ("PluginName")]

   #endif

   private static extern float FooPluginFunction ();

   void Awake () {
      // Calls the FooPluginFunction inside the plugin
      // And prints 5 to the console
      print (FooPluginFunction ());
   }
}
```

Do note you can't do all of the platforms you want to do with a single c++ dll. You will need to compile a dll per platform, you can put the files in seperate subfolders so all dll files can use the same name to make your C# code easier. You then can use the [PluginInspector](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginInspector.html) to set which platform which dll should be used at runtime.